# Can we monitor a form's POST method in Firebug or TCP dump?

Tags: jquery, html, tcp, security

I just have doubt can we monitor form's post method in Firebug or TCP dump?

If yes so how can we made post method of an HTML form secure? As we can observe post or get method of jQuery in Firebug as well.

Comment: If you are using Firefox, you might want to check out [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/), showing all HTTP (as well as HTTPS) communications in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use `firebug` to monitor the form's post data, but you could only see the data you posted (which is quite obvious),  so there is no secure problem.

For tcp dump, yes, someone could use it to monitor the post data, so this is why the website need to use `Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS)` to protect the data.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it in the `Net` panel, by clicking on the request, and observing it's contents. See image below:

[image]

This is using Mozilla Firefox 15.0.1